# Unable to synchronize ntp with servers

Tags: ubuntu, ntp, ntpd

I have gone through several tutorials regarding NTP and synchronizing the system clock, but I am still not able to get my system's time right. I followed the following steps on a machine running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

1. Installed `ntp` and `ntpdate`
2. Edited the `/etc/ntp.conf` file to contain the following:

   ```
   driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
   server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
   server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst
   server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst
   server 3.pool.ntp.org iburst`
   ```
3. Started the `ntp` service with `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp start`

To check if everything was working, I ran `ntpstat` and got this output:

```
unsynchronised
   polling server every 8 s
```

Checking with `ntpdc -c peers` returned:

```
localhost: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

`ntpq -p` gives:

```
   `remote          refid           st t when poll reach   delay    offset jitter`
   `==============================================================================`
   `propjet.latt.ne .INIT.          16 u    -  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000`
   `duffman.whacker .INIT.          16 u    -  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000`
   `ec2-52-6-191-28 .INIT.          16 u    -  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000`

   `104.131.53.252  .INIT.          16 u    -  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000`
```

Even after all of this, my clock is still off by almost 10 minutes, and I'm not sure what the issue is.

I am running a local machine, but it is behind a corporate proxy. However, I've included the proxy information as environment variables.

Are there any corrections that I can make to fix this?

Comment: Your computer cannot communicate with the NTP servers. Investigate why. Can you ping `www.google.com`? Also, on 16.04 you really should use `sudo systemctl start ntp` not call directly the script in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: Are you running a local machine or a server in a datacenter/cloud service? NTP has been used for amplification DoS attacks in the past, so it's possible that your provider blocks in/out NTP traffic.

Comment: @AlexP i cannot ping `www.google.com`.

@UlrichSchwarz I am running a local machine, but it is behind a corporate proxy. However, I've included the proxy information as environment variables.

Comment: If you cannot ping `www.google.com` then your computer does not have direct access to the internet. You may be behind a corporate firewall. Ask the local gurus for the time servers on the intranet.

Comment: 1) ask IT folks 2) try local router as ntp server.

Answer (score 2):

> I am running a local machine, but it is behind a corporate proxy. However, I've included the proxy information as environment variables

Web proxy information is irrelevant to non-HTTP protocols such as NTP. You will need to speak with your corporate IT group to get them to give you access either to their local NTP servers, or to the set of external NTP servers you propose to use. (It would be possible in the second case that you would have to define that set of servers rather than using the dynamic `*.pool.ntp.org` names.)

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of ntp questions and they all have the same mistake: people using SERVER on an ntp pool and POOL on an ntp server:

```
server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

As the URL says, it's a POOL. Try

```
pool 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

instead or actually use a server, not a pool ...

Furthermore, most people have a timesource in their network, most often Windows Domain Controllers. If this is true for you, why messing with external ntp servers when you could use internal NTP of Windows DC ...

(I am not sure if you can use iburst on a pool.)

Comment: They don't "all have the same mistake". True, the relatively new `pool` keyword should in a growing number of places be used instead of `server`, but `server` is not wrong merely suboptimal. In the particular situation here, it's likely that `pool` would exacerbate the problem by hiding the necessary IP addresses and making it even harder to get the data through what turns out to be a corporate firewall.